# What is the latest OS X version that will run on a Powerbook G4?

Tags: macos, g4, powerbook

I have a Powerbook G4 that someone gave me with a blank hard drive. I'd like to install OS X on it, but the only version listed on apple.com is Snow Leopard, which only supports Intel processors.

What version of OS X can I use with this G4, and any ideas where I can obtain it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can probably shoehorn 10.5 on there, but 10.6 is Intel only.

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mac_OS_X_10.5) says that you need a 867MHz processor, 512 MB of RAM, and 9 G of drive space.  As well, you'll need a DVD drive to get it installed, unless you have some other tricky method (like installing from an external HD).

Comment: Typo correction: the minimum CPU speed is 867MHz.

Comment: You're right.  I've fixed my typo.

Answer (score 1):

You could Install Leopard 10.5, but if you don't have much ram You may want to install Tiger 10.4 instead.

Answer (score 1):

[Mac OS X 10.5 Leopard](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000FK88JK).

I run it on my 1.5GHz G4 PowerBook with 1GB of memory, and it runs OK for light tasks like browsing the Web, emailing, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to upgrade to Leopard (10.5) without any trouble.  Leopard is the last that will work with the PowerPC procs, though.

Answer (score 0):

I've installed Mac OS X 10.5 on my iBook G4 and it runs fine. In some areas it is much faster than 10.4, plus you get to have “Spaces”.